# Realization of the log in system

Tags: security, networking, server, request

I am trying to make my own realization of the messanger. How could I make the server sure  that my queries are sent by myself? I have done a system when you print your login and password and if they are correct the server sends you your id. Then you print your id and your query. For example SendMessage/1/2/"hello"
Where 1 is my id and 2 is my friends id to whom I want to send a message. Is it a good system? Maybe you could tell me how should I make it

I tried to do it with id request but I think it is a very unsecure way

Comment: What programming related question do you have?